# Layer(div) in table TD element line-break

Tags: css

I am trying to make layer(div) box in table TD element. 
The problem is the texts are automatically line breaks. I think because its in table cell.

I want the layer box width is fluid but max-width is 400px; 
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Here is demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/671474hx/160/

```
    <style>
   .box { position:relative;}
.layer { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:30px; left:30px; border:1px solid #000;   max-width:400px; background:#eee  }

     </style>

<table class="list_member" border=1>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>

      <div class="box">
      td
        <div class="layer">
        text text text text text text text text text text text 
        </div>
      </div>

    </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is broken, I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give your .layer class a max-width. Change it to a fixed width and the text will wrap in the container.

```
.layer{
 width: 300px;
}
```